# Is it possible in HTML to separate a comma-delimited .txt file into seperate columns?

Tags: html

The text file has thousands of devices, the text file needs to be read and put into two seperate columns

text file name is servers.txt,  ive tried searching on stackoverflow already and could not get it to work properly.

Example text is:

test,server

test1,server

test2,server

Comment: can't understand your question. Please elaborate

Comment: I think you need ServerSide Programming lang like `Php, Python, GO, etc..` if you're planning to use something like Nodejs you can use `fs` or `readline` module to do that

Comment: Sounds like you could do it in an Access database with simple queries or a spreadsheet with some VBA.

Answer (score 0):

If you can do this outside of `HTML`, try the following.

Copy your data into a spreadsheet (the 'Original' column below):

[image]

The formula for 'Left' is:

```
=LEFT(K6,SEARCH(",",K6)-1)
```

The formula for 'Right' is:

```
=MID(K6, SEARCH(",",K6) + 1,LEN(K6))
```

You can't do this "in HTML." As mentioned in the comments, you'll need a server-side programming language, or possibly JavaScript, or do it by hand, as above, and copy it back wherever you need it.

The question is a bit unclear so it's hard to tell what will work the best.